# CoreData MagicalRecord crash: Fatal Exception: NSObjectInaccessibleException

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext, magicalrecord

I have seen a few other threads about this, but haven't found a good solution. This is the crash that I'm seeing in crash reports, though I can't reproduce it myself:

```
Fatal Exception: NSObjectInaccessibleException
CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0xd00000001ff80004...
```

Here is the exact code where it happens:

```
NSDictionary *newCats = (cats from server)

[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {

    NSMutableSet *existingIds = [NSMutableSet set];

    NSArray *allCats = [Cat MR_findAllInContext:localContext];
    for (Cat *cat in allCats) {
        if (cat.managedObjectContext != nil) {
            [existingIds addObject:cat.cat_id]; //CRASH!!!
        }
    }

    NSMutableArray *newIds = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSDictionary *catData in newCats) {
        NSString *catId = catData[@"id"];
        [newIds addObject:catId];
        [existingIds removeObject:catId];
    }

    for (NSString *sId in existingIds) {
        Cat *cat = [Cat MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"cat_id" withValue:sId inContext:localContext];
        [cat MR_deleteEntityInContext:localContext];
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm just trying to gather a list of existing ids, so I can compare with ids received from the server, and delete local Cats that no longer exist on the server.

Can anyone shed any light on this? Users are seeing a ton of crashes here.

Comment: Are you deleting `Cat` instances somewhere else? This answer might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327973/core-data-nsobjectinaccessibleexception-when-attempting-to-delete/19328747#19328747

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The only deletion I'm doing is in the code above, below where the crash occurs . So I assume execution never reaches that point.